# Get the current window/buffer/tabpage in Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, macvim

In python, when using the vim module, it is incredibly simple to get the current window/buffer/tabpage:

```
current_win = vim.current.window
current_buff = vim.current.buffer
current_tabpage = vim.current.tabpage
```

My question is, how do you do this in pure VimL / Vimscript and what type of object is returned? I really can't seem to find this anywhere in `windows.txt` (`:h windows`).

Comment: `:h functions` makes more sense for you to find script related info.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well… it's just as simple in vimscript.

#### Current window

Python:

```
current_win = vim.current.window
```

Vimscript:

```
let current_win = winnr()
```

#### Current buffer

Python:

```
current_buff = vim.current.buffer
```

Vimscript:

```
let current_buff = bufnr("%")
```

#### Current tabpage

Python:

```
current_tabpage = vim.current.tabpage
```

Vimscript:

```
let current_tabpage = tabpagenr()
```

See `:help functions`.

Comment: Is there a vimscript function to make a buffer active by its id?